# c++ console Check adjacent elements for duplicates

Tags: c++, duplicates, element

I have a grid of randomly generated numbers of size `gameSize` (user input) which is contained within a vector of vectors. The user can enter two co-ordinates (x, y) so that it changes a number within the grid to a predefined value, which is "0".

So for example the user enters, X:0 Y:0 and:

```
{9, 7, 9}

{9, 6, 8}

{5, 1, 4}
```

becomes:

```
{0, 7, 9} <-- Changes position 0,0 to 0 (the predefined value)

{9, 6, 8} 

{5, 1, 4}
```

For example, the following would not be allowed because three 0's clash.

```
    {0, 0, 9}

    {0, 6, 8}

    {5, 1, 4}
```

But the following WOULD be valid:

```
{0, 7, 0}

{9, 0, 8}

{5, 1, 4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (
    (row == 0 || myGame[row-1][col] != 0) // element above (if applicable)
    && (row == gameSize-1 || myGame[row+1][col] != 0) // element below
    && (col == 0 || myGame[row][col-1] != 0) // element to the left
    && (col == gameSize-1 || myGame[row][col+1] != 0) // element to the right
    )
    myGame[row][col] = 0;
else
...
```

Each condition checks for an adjacent element only if it's there (taking advantage of *short-circuit evaluation*, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) under Logical operators). In other words, for instance, `myGame[row-1][col]` is checked only if `row == 0` is false, thus preventing crashes due to unauthorized memory accesses.